# R - Why does R change '#' to '.' when reading a .csv file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I am reading in a .csv file where the column names are of the form:

```
'reported_#_date', 'reported_#_date2' etc
```

The issue is when I read it in:

```
data <- read.csv("mydata.csv")
```

These column names are now changed to

```
'reported_._date', 'reported_._date2'
```

Normally this would not be a big difference, but these column names are my PID and I need to reference them in elsewhere as well, which retain the original name. Does anyone know why R does this? Is there a way to prevent it from changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is because the column names are being checked - R's `make.names` function, which is called when the `check.names` argument of `read.csv` is TRUE, replaces all invalid characters in names with the '.' character. You can set `check.names = FALSE` in your `read.csv` call to stop that happening.